# Convert list into dataframe using tags as the values of a new column (with R)

Tags: r, data-transform

I have a list like this:

```
require(tidyverse)
months <- c("january", "february", "march", "october", "december") 
weekdays <- c("Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday")
seasons <- c("Summer", "Winter", "Fall", "autumn")
timeWords_list <- tibble::lst(months,  weekdays, seasons)
```

I want to convert this list into a two columns-data.frame:
I need all the values of the list to be in the first column
And the tags to be the values of the second column

The result should be like this:

```
df <- data.frame(first_column  = c("january", "february", "march", "october", "december", "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Summer", "Winter", "Fall", "autumn"), 
                 second_column = c("months", "months", "months", "months", "months", "weekdays", "weekdays" ,"weekdays", "seasons", "seasons", "seasons", "seasons"))
```

The second column could be a string or a factor, but should correspond to tags of the list. Note that the list could be of different sizes and its elements could have different lengths.

Answer (score 1):

An easy option is `stack` from `base R`

```
df1 <- stack(timeWords_list)
names(df1) <- c("first_column", "second_column")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `stack` approach by [@akrun](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65588200/12158757) is the most efficient one so far. Here is another base R option using `unlist` + `rep`

```
data.frame(
  first_col = unlist(timeWords_list, use.names = FALSE),
  second_col = rep(names(timeWords_list), lengths(timeWords_list))
)
```

which gives

```
   first_col second_col
1    january     months
2   february     months
3      march     months
4    october     months
5   december     months
6     Sunday   weekdays
7     Monday   weekdays
8    Tuesday   weekdays
9     Summer    seasons
10    Winter    seasons
11      Fall    seasons
12    autumn    seasons
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `tibble::enframe` and `tidyr::unnest`

```
tibble::enframe(timeWords_list,name = 'first_column',value = 'second_column') %>%
  tidyr::unnest(second_column)

# first_column second_column
#   <chr>        <chr>        
# 1 months       january      
# 2 months       february     
# 3 months       march        
# 4 months       october      
# 5 months       december     
# 6 weekdays     Sunday       
# 7 weekdays     Monday       
# 8 weekdays     Tuesday      
# 9 seasons      Summer       
#10 seasons      Winter       
#11 seasons      Fall         
#12 seasons      autumn
```